# how to read local excel file using webapi?

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-web-api

```
public class ExcelParserController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get(string templatePath)
    {
        ExcelParser excelParser = new ExcelParser();
        return excelParser.Parse(templatePath);
    }
}
```

This is my first idea. But I cannot know how to read local excel file from server. `templatePath` is like `"C:\1.xlsx"`. How to open local file by using webapi?

Comment: This excel file... it is on the WebServer? Or on the Client machine?
and is your question more about "how USE the file" or "how to access the file"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the OpenXML SDK to access Office documents including Excel files.

Here's a sample from the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg575571.aspx

```
public static void OpenSpreadsheetDocument(string filepath)
{
    // Open a SpreadsheetDocument based on a filepath.
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, false))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
        SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
        string text;
        foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
        {
            foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
            {
                text = c.CellValue.Text;
                Console.Write(text + " ");
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for ASPOSE.CELL you can utilize it's API, they also provide trial, so you can check if it helps in your work.
[Aspose.cells](http://www.aspose.com/.net/excel-component.aspx)

They also provide many tutorials.

Comment: just to clarify, why u didn't  like my answer
justify your down vote by commenting, it will help me

Answer (score -1):

A quick search of the internet and you come across the following article with simple examples on how to read xls and xlsx files using c#.

[CodeProjects article on reading/writing Excel files](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/813187/Csharp-Read-and-Write-Excel-xls-and-xlsx-Files-Con)

Take one of these examples and adopt it to fit your needs, where the example asks you to specify the path to the file, simply pass in your "templatePath" string.

Once the excel data has been read into your NPOI workbook or your dataset (Depending on the option you take) you should be able to use linq to return the IEnumerable data that you require.

Comment: "go to this link and follow their tutorial" isn't really helpful